# Sample result's label is not changed through BeanShell post processor for some conditions

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell, jmeter-5.0

I made this code so that if status == 500 the name of the api would be equal to "FAKE_CLIENT_RETRY", if the status of the api == "ERROR", the name would be equal to "FAKE_CLIENT_CALLBACK_ERROR"

```
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;

//process main sample
if(("${status}").equals("500")) {

    SampleResult.setResponseCodeOK();
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(true);
    
vars.put("Api_Fake_Client_Name","FAKE_CLIENT_RETRY");
     
}else if(("${status}").equals("ERROR")){
    
        SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
vars.put("Api_Fake_Client_Name","FAKE_CLIENT_CALLBACK_ERROR");

}else{
vars.put("Api_Fake_Client_Name","FAKE_CLIENT_CALLBACK_SUCESS");
    
}
```

But even when status == "ERROR" the name it returns is "FAKE_CLIENT_RETRY"

The strangest thing is that I know that the execution entered the "if" of the condition == "ERROR", because the return that comes with status == "ERROR" appears with execution failure in Jmeter and I forced the return in this case to return with fails via code snippet:

```
SampleResult.setSuccessful (false);
```

But despite having entered, it ignores the snippet that asks to rename the api.

Jmeter Sreenshot ---->  [Jmeter response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4Jzs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following script worked without any issue within [BeanShell Post Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor)

```
if(("${status}").equals("500")) {
        prev.setResponseCodeOK();
        prev.setSuccessful(true);
        prev.setSampleLabel("FAKE_CLIENT_RETRY");
        vars.put("Api_Fake_Client_Name","FAKE_CLIENT_RETRY");
        
     
}else if(("${status}").equals("ERROR")){
        prev.setSuccessful(false);
        prev.setSampleLabel("FAKE_CLIENT_CALLBACK_ERROR");
        vars.put("Api_Fake_Client_Name","FAKE_CLIENT_CALLBACK_ERROR");

}else{
        prev.setSampleLabel("FAKE_CLIENT_CALLBACK_SUCESS");
        vars.put("Api_Fake_Client_Name","FAKE_CLIENT_CALLBACK_SUCESS");
    
}
```

[image]

Please note that you have access to the SampleResult through the variable `previous`. Lets use `prev.setSampleLabel("Label");` to set the label of the sample result.

> prev - (SampleResult) - gives access to the previous SampleResult

> Migration to JSR223 PostProcessor+Groovy is highly recommended for performance, support of new Java features and limited maintenance of the BeanShell library

Add a Debug Post Processor to view the JMeter variables through view result tree.

[Sample test plan (JMX)](https://github.com/pragmatictesters/Pragmatic-Learning-JMeter-Examples/blob/master/post-processors/TestPlan-Examples-SOF-Beanshell-SetSampleResults.jmx) is available in GitHub.

Comment: I am very grateful for your answer, I will study further as I did not know this "prev.set Sample Label".

Answer (score 2):

You're setting an `Api_Fake_Client_Name` variable value in the Assertion, it will be available (updated) either in the next sampler of during the next iteration of the current sampler:

[image]

Also be aware that starting from JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to be using [JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) so you could change your code to something like:

```
switch (vars.get('status')) {
    case '500':
        prev.setResponseCodeOK()
        prev.setSuccessful(true)
        vars.put('Api_Fake_Client_Name', 'FAKE_CLIENT_RETRY');
        prev.setSampleLabel('FAKE_CLIENT_RETRY')
        break;
    case 'ERROR':
        prev.setSuccessful(false)
        vars.put('Api_Fake_Client_Name', 'FAKE_CLIENT_CALLBACK_ERROR')
        prev.setSampleLabel('FAKE_CLIENT_CALLBACK_ERROR')
        break;
    default:
        vars.put('Api_Fake_Client_Name', 'FAKE_CLIENT_CALLBACK_SUCESS')
        prev.setSampleLabel('FAKE_CLIENT_CALLBACK_SUCESS')
}
```

More information:

- [JMeter Test Elements Execution Order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder)
- [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the tips too.